# Should [probe] be made a synonym with [space-probes]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed when asking a question involving space probes that two tags came up in the autocomplete thingy: [probe](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probe) and [space-probes](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-probes). Is there any reason that [space-probes](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-probes) shouldn't be a synonym of [probe](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probe)?

I don't have a high enough score to suggest it, so I can't really help synonimize it - I'm just throwing it out here so it gets noticed.

Comment: I went ahead and made the [tag:space-probes] a synonym of  [tag:probe]. We'll see how that feels like, and change accordingly, if it will present some problems. But I didn't wait for more support, it's been rather dead in our meta of late, so no point in sitting on our behinds alone, is it? (why talk the talk, when we can walk the walk...) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe they should be made as synonyms. Thinking of previous arguments brought forward in the [Use of the word “Space” in a tag](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/85/49), [Should [space-law] be just [law]?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/49), [Can we make the [space-sickness] and [motion-sickness] tags synonyms?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/252/49), and other similar threads, there seems to be the prevailing thought that the use of "space" in tags is synonymous with the scope of this website and as such (mostly) unneeded. But on the other hand, also hard to get rid of, so tags with "space" in them might persist, no matter how hard we try.

So I'm all for it to make these two tags synonyms, and simply let posters decide which one they prefer, and at the same time indicate, that we mean [space-probes](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-probes) with [probe](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probe) (on input of "probe", all tags with this keyword and all synonyms would display as suggestions to use instead), and if they had any other probes in mind (atmospheric-, seismic-, proximity-,...), they can create a new tag to further differentiate between them.

Comment: Which should be a synonym of which, though?

Comment: @Undo - In all honesty, I don't think it really matters. Any thought where that actually makes a difference? Plus, it's really easy for mods to swap which one is the master and which one a synonym of it, so we can try it out either way and then change our minds. :)

Comment: I'd say [tag:space-probes] is a synonym -> of master [tag:probe], in line with our detest for space-prefixed tags :)

Answer (score -1):

The term space-probe may include both space, and surface probe to Celestials

E.g. Curiosity

Let us keep the two separate; Then create an alias 'surface probe' to be used interchangeably with 'probe'.